# Conditional matching based on two variables

Tags: r

I have a DF with similar multiple rows and columns. I want to match `Name` with `Name1`. If `Name` does not match `Name1`, I want to also try to match`Name` to `Name3`.  Then if it matches, I want the value of `Name2` to return as a new variable, `Namevalue`.

```
df
Name      Name1    Name2   Name3
Natalie   Shawn    Edmund  Natalie
Desmond   Desmond  James   Sue
Kylie     Kylie    Brent   Manny
```

Desired output

```
df
Name      Name1    Name2   Name3     Namevalue
Natalie   Shawn    Edmund  Natalie   Edmund
Desmond   Desmond  Tyler   Sue       Tyler
Kylie     Chris    Tam     Kylie     Tam
Leah      Chewie   Luke    Solo      Unknown
```

I've tried this:

```
Merge1$Namevalue <- ifelse(Merge1$Name %in% Merge1$Name1, Merge1$Name2, 
                    paste("Unknown"),
                    ifelse(Merge1$Name %in% Merge1$Name3, Merge1$Name2, paste("Unknown"))
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work where it doesn't match properly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ifelse()` idea was a good start, however, you got the condition slightly wrong, hope this helps:

**Code**

Test: if there is a match in `name1` **or** (|) in `name3`, assign `name2`:

```
df$Namevalue <- ifelse(df$Name %in% df$Name1 | df$Name %in% df$Name3,
                       df$Name2,
                       NA)
#
     Name   Name1  Name2   Name3 Namevalue
1 Natalie   Shawn Edmund Natalie    Edmund
2 Desmond Desmond  Tyler     Sue     Tyler
3   Kylie   Chris    Tam   Kylie       Tam
4    Leah  Chewie   Luke    Solo      <NA>
```

---

**Updated Answer**

If one wants to know if `name1` or `name3` was a match.

You can first match only against `name1`,

```
df$Namevalue <- ifelse(df$Name %in% df$Name1,
                       df$Name2,
                       NA)
#
     Name   Name1  Name2   Name3 Namevalue
1 Natalie   Shawn Edmund Natalie      <NA>
2 Desmond Desmond  Tyler     Sue     Tyler
3   Kylie   Chris    Tam   Kylie      <NA>
4    Leah  Chewie   Luke    Solo      <NA>
```

then create a column that displays if there was a match against `name1`,

```
df$match <- rep(NA, length(df$Namevalue))
df$match[which(!is.na(df$Namevalue))] <- "Name1"
#
     Name   Name1  Name2   Name3 Namevalue match
1 Natalie   Shawn Edmund Natalie      <NA>  <NA>
2 Desmond Desmond  Tyler     Sue     Tyler Name1
3   Kylie   Chris    Tam   Kylie      <NA>  <NA>
4    Leah  Chewie   Luke    Solo      <NA>  <NA>
```

then match against `name3` and assign `name3` (in the last column) to values  that have no match with `name1` but a match with `name3`,

```
df$Namevalue <- ifelse(df$Name %in% df$Name3 & is.na(df$Namevalue),
                       df$Name2,
                       df$Namevalue)
#
df$match[which(is.na(df$match) & !is.na(df$Namevalue))] <- "Name3"
#
     Name   Name1  Name2   Name3 Namevalue match
1 Natalie   Shawn Edmund Natalie    Edmund Name3
2 Desmond Desmond  Tyler     Sue     Tyler Name1
3   Kylie   Chris    Tam   Kylie       Tam Name3
4    Leah  Chewie   Luke    Solo      <NA>  <NA>
```

the remaining `NA's` have no match in `name1` or `name3`.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Name      Name1    Name2   Name3    
Natalie   Shawn    Edmund  Natalie   
Desmond   Desmond  Tyler   Sue       
Kylie     Chris    Tam     Kylie     
Leah      Chewie   Luke    Solo", header = T, stringsAsFactor = F)
#
     Name   Name1  Name2   Name3
1 Natalie   Shawn Edmund Natalie
2 Desmond Desmond  Tyler     Sue
3   Kylie   Chris    Tam   Kylie
4    Leah  Chewie   Luke    Solo
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I got this far before I saw your post (which makes me feel somewhat competent).  The issue I'm having is that the value it returns needs to be the exact row associated where it matches.  The code I used in the past where I didn't need to use the OR condition was this:     
          DF$Namevalue <- 
            (DF$SSBA[match(DF$Name, Df$Name1)])
But in the present question, I need that extra OR condition and the value needs to return where it matches.  Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am away from my computer now. An approach would be to split it into two ifelse() statements. First match against name1 and assign 1 to an additional column.Then match again with another ifelse() statement, the remaining NA's are no match and the new colum indicates if you matched in your first run (with name 1).

Comment: Thanks. No rush. I can wait for your expert answer.